# css in head not accounted for

Tags: css, wordpress

I am developing a website on wordpress using the theme "Virtue". I have added custom css to change the appearance/behaviour of some elements.
Here is a link to the site: http://deepdive.ma/test5182/
When I open the site, the custom css is not accounted for.

To take a specific example: the menu should be in a light blue color (#e7ecf1), but it is white.
When I use DOM inspector:

- The content of my custom css is included in head, including css for the class .headerclass;
- But the styling element 'header class="banner headerclass" role="banner"' does not refer to it. It only refers to elements.style, then to external style sheets (default.css; virtue.css; ...).
  It's probably something stupid but I really can't find the problem. Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not properly closing `.home .page .wide`. You need the closing `}` in Line 32.

```
.home .page .wide{
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  left:auto;
  right:auto;
}
```

A suggestion: why not customize the theme's CSS instead of dropping the new CSS inline in the HTML document. It'll avoid major headaches.